# infinite loop while using modwrite in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What am trying to do in that code is:
Any visitor click on an href like http://domain.com/article.php?id=44 the .htaccess will transfer him to domain/article/44

then another rewrite rule to to get the content of requested id from the file article.php

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ http://alarabe.org/article/%1?
RewriteRule ^article/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This rule isn't right and will certainly cause looping. You need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable that represents original request received by Apache from your browser.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+article\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://alarabe.org/article/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^article/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you qualify why the rule "isn't right" and explain why THE_REQUEST provides any benefits over a condition that examines a query string then redirects if both URL and query string match the conditions? Is the absence of the [R] flag not the problem?

Comment: No it is due to the fact that `THE_REQUEST` variable doesn't change its value after application of some rules. Where as `QUERY_STRING` and `REQUEST_URI` values get updated in rewrite loop.

Comment: I didn't ask the question!

Comment: @arco444: Apologies! I thought you are OP :)