# Redirect php links with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site with a video player, created with php.
I have mangaged to clean up the URL from `www.website.com/player.php?id=10`
to `www.website.com/player/10`, where `10` is the id for a given video.

The code for the .htaccess file is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^player/([0-9]+)$ player.php?id=$1
```

This works fine if I directly enter `www.website.com/player/10`, however, if someone tries to access the old links, they are not redirected. How can I do this in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Rewrites doesn't redirect to the new URL. It simply takes a matched URL and internally calling the other URL. To have a better control over it, I would recommend that you look into using some router instead.

Comment: You can use `.htaccess` to set up another Redirect rule for the original `player.php` URL. [This Q&A may help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421068/htaccess-301-redirect-of-single-page)

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between *Redirect* and *Rewrite*.

*Redirecting* issues an HTTP header to the client forcing them to request the new location.  *Rewriting* is internal to the server and maps the requested location to a different one.

So, just redirect the "*old*" style to the "*new*" style and rewrite the "*new*" style:

```
# Match id in the query string and capture the id
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^id=(.*)$         [NC]
# Redirect the old to the new player/id
RewriteRule ^player.php$        player/%1         [NC,R=301,L]
# Rewrite the new to the old
RewriteRule ^player/([0-9]+)$   player.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think you can access the get params like that in your first rewrite rule.

Comment: @ChinLeung:  You're probably right.  Does that look better?

Comment: Your rule is going to loop as `player.php?id=$1` of your second Rule also matches the Rewrite pattern and RewriteCond of the first one. To prevent this loop ,you need to match against `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable instead of `%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: @starkeen: You'll have to be more specific about what matches what, I don't see it.

Comment: See this similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578126/infinite-loop-while-using-modwrite-in-htaccess